# Spark: MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2 - strange memory behavior

Tags: scala, memory, apache-spark, persist

I am storing an RDD using a storageLevel = `MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2` in case if one executor lost, there is another copy of data.

[image]

Then I found something strange:

1. The **Size in Memory** of 2xReplicated RDD seems to be the same comparing when I used storageLevel = `MEMORY_ONLY_SER` (1xReplicated)
2. Fraction Cached couldn't reach 100% even though I still have a lot of storage memory left.

Am I understanding storageLevel = `MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2` correctly? why 2xReplicated doesn't have twice the **Size in Memory** compared with 1xReplicated ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe all your memory for cached is used, so no matter how many replication you used.

I do not know how many memory allocated for every executor, if you allocated a lot, you can increase the value of *`spark.storage.memoryFraction`*, the default values is `0.6`.

If you just to verify whether the `MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2` will cost as twice as the  `MEMORY_ONLY_SER`, you can use a small dataset.